# THEOS: Shell Terminal Commands using THEOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, jailbreak, ipod, theos

I am making a jailbreak app using theos for iPhone. But, I need to know how to run terminal commands using theos to complete my app. Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `system("yourcommand");`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it when I get home! I didn't realize it's the same as in C++ or other ones, the system command!